# При записи объекта в PostgreSQL не отрабатывает генератор последовательности: "null value in column [] of relation [] violates not-null constraint"

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Всем привет! Прошу помощи. Пересмотрела массу тем с подобной ошибкой, но решение для себя не нашла.
При записи объекта в `PostgreSQL` не отрабатывает генератор последовательности. 
Выдает ошибку:

> ERROR: null value in column "doc_number" of relation "receiving_acts" violates not-null constraint

Более детально:

```
"org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not
execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [doc_number\" of relation
\"receiving_acts].
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not
execute statement. org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null
value in column \"doc_number\" of relation \"receiving_acts\" violates
not-null constraint\n  Подробности: Failing row contains
(feba8451-de26-47c2-9fe2-5381318d8deb, null, 2023-03-01 14:42:03+02,
f, 47a9bb21-fa67-4ff7-bf33-e276d23a19eb)."
```

Есть класс `Entity`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "receiving_acts")
@Getter
@Setter
public class ReceivingAct extends AbstractDocumentEntity {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "ra_dn_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "ra_dn_gen", sequenceName = "receiving_acts_doc_number_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "doc_number")
    private Integer docNumber;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "contractor_id", nullable = false)
    private Contractor contractor;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "receivingAct", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<ReceivingActTSVehiclesLine> tableVehicles;
}
```

Поле `@Id` типа `UUID` находится в классе `AbstractDocumentEntity` и с ним проблем нет, генератор отрабатывает. 
`DDL` создание таблицы:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS receiving_acts_doc_number_seq AS INTEGER INCREMENT BY 1;

CREATE TABLE receiving_acts
(
    id            UUID                     NOT NULL DEFAULT gen_random_uuid(),
    doc_number    INTEGER                  NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('receiving_acts_doc_number_seq'),
    date_time     TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
    marked        BOOLEAN                  NOT NULL,
    contractor_id UUID                     NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_receiving_acts PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (contractor_id) REFERENCES contractors (id)
);
```

Метод в классе-контроллере:

```
@PostMapping("/")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public ReceivingActResponse createReceivingAct(@RequestBody ReceivingActRequest docRequest) {
    ReceivingAct docEntity = receivingActMapper.toReceivingActEntity(docRequest);
    ReceivingAct savedDocEntity = receivingActService.add(docEntity);
    return receivingActMapper.toReceivingActResponse(savedDocEntity);
}
```

Метод `add` в классе `ReceivingActServiceImpl`:

```
@Override
public ReceivingAct add(ReceivingAct receivingAct) {
    return receivingActRepository.save(receivingAct);
}
```

Метод `save` стандартный из репозитория `ReceivingActRepository`:

```
public interface ReceivingActRepository extends JpaRepository<ReceivingAct, UUID> {
}
```

`JSON` post-запроса:

```
{
    "docDateTime": "2023-03-03 11:53:56",
    "contractorId": "47a9bb21-fa67-4ff7-bf33-e276d23a19eb",
    "tableVehicles": [
        {
            "grossWeight": 1564.910,
            "vinCodeId": "d7094b75-fefc-4745-a4b6-4c5d4a2f97c3",
            "cellId": "bba1f527-a815-41ac-bbf9-aa5433d2d888"
        }
    ]
}
```

В итоге при создании объекта `docNumber` инициализируется `null`, как и `id`. Но `id` возвращается сгенерированным, а `docNumber` нет. 
Меняла тип `Integer` на `int`, генерация не происходит, инициализируется 0 и 0 записывается. 
 
Последовательность в БД создана, к полю привязана. Если руками добавлять строку, то `docNumber` генерируется. 
 
Пробовала в `@Column` добавлять `columnDefinition = "integer default nextval('receiving_acts_doc_number_seq')`, не помогло. 
 
Уже не знаю куда смотреть, куда копать. Может самому как-то надо генерировать, до сохранения, но это ж нелогично. Может когда есть еще одна последовательность, то нужен другой подход.

Comment: А можете показать, как вы сохраняете в базу документ? (метод receivingActService.add)

Comment: @РусланМамедов дополнила вопрос методом, в принципе там стандартная логика добавления из репозитория, своего особенного добавления нет.

Comment: Странно, columnDefinition должен был решить проблему. Тут походу какая-то детская ошибка. Можете мне в телегу написать, данные в профиле, я постараюсь помочь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы hibernate не использовал поле при вставке вы можете указать это поле как игнорируемое (insertable = false)

```java
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "ra_dn_gen")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "ra_dn_gen", sequenceName = "receiving_acts_doc_number_seq", allocationSize = 1)
@Column(name = "doc_number", insertable=false) // <--
private Integer docNumber;
```

Второй вариант: добавляем аннотацию @Generated(GenerationTime.INSERT), чтобы объяснить хиберу, что это поле будет генерироваться базой данных и его не нужно вставлять.

```java
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "ra_dn_gen")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "ra_dn_gen", sequenceName = "receiving_acts_doc_number_seq", allocationSize = 1)
@Column(name = "doc_number")
@Generated(value = GenerationTime.INSERT) // <--
private Integer docNumber;
```

Второй вариант мне нравится больше, т.к сразу после сохранения в сущности окажется сгенерируемое поле. В первом варианте придется писать логику получения сущности.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за помощь!
Воспользовалась вторым вариантом, то что надо, и сгенерировалось и вернулось значение)